# Can substitution rules be compiled?

Tags: symbolic, compile

I am thinking of having a custom multiplication operation `CenterDot[A,B]` for non-commutative operators, and some rules that should commute the operators to a desired ordering. The calculation would be very time intensive, while manipulations would just be trivial swapping of entries and addition of other entries. Therefore, I wonder if there is any (perhaps hacky?) way to `Compile` a code of this type in Mathematica? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Let's say you could compile it. You are aware of the fact that a compiled function only takes *numerical arguments* of a specific, pre-determined type, yes? Can you provide the code for `CenterDot` and a small example on how to use it?

Comment: @halirutan Yes, now I'm thinking of some way to only use lists and integers as labels, since `AppendTo` is compilable. I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: When you have a minimal example that works without compiling, then we can have a look at it and discuss if it is compilable.

Comment: Perhaps [Dispatch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) would be useful?

Comment: @WReach It is indeed interesting. Unfortunately it does not appear in the list of compilable functions though. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions